# CustomAction ScriptSrc not loading script

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-actions

I have a script called Translate.js on my SharePoint online site.

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/demo/Style%20Library/docs/Scripts/Translate.js
```

When I use the code below and try to include the script in my `CustomAction`, it just says that translate is not defined, Basic because it doesn't load my script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="TranslationRibbonExtension"
    ScriptSrc="~SiteCollection/Style%20Library/docs/Scripts/Translate.js"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.PubPageActions.Controls._children">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.PubPageActions.TranslationButton"
            Alt="Translate Page"
            Sequence="100"
            Command="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.PubPageActions.TranslationButton.TranslatePage"
            CommandType="General"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-120" Image16by16Left="-32"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-192" Image32by32Left="-224"
            LabelText="Translate Page"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
            ToolTipTitle="Translate Page"
            ToolTipDescription="Translate Page"
            />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.PubPageActions.TranslationButton.TranslatePage"
          CommandAction="javascript:
            translate('da', 'en', 'Hej mit navn er John Doe!');
          "/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Can someone tell why ScriptSrc dont load the script?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460194.aspx) of CustomAction:

ScriptSrc:

Optional Text. Specifies a file that contains script to be executed. This attribute is only applicable when the **Location** attribute is set to **ScriptLink**.

So you need to do something like [Load an external JavaScript file on demand using a Custom Action in SharePoint 2007](http://www.alaindeklerk.com/load-an-external-javascript-file-on-demand-using-a-custom-action-in-sharepoint-2007/)